# Android http server not accessible from other devices on network intermittently

Tags: android, service, nanohttpd

I'm using NanoHTTPD to present a web server in an android app. I'm using a wifi lock to keep the network alive, and a CPU lock to keep the cpu awake, and keeping it running via a foreground service so that it should never die.

What i'm finding is that it'll be accessible from other devices for half an hour, and then not accessible for half an hour. Whenever it becomes inaccessible, I can open safari on the android device and browse to 0.0.0.0:30000 and verify that the server is indeed running. And i also check to make sure the wifi is connected which it appears to be.

Any suggestions of where to look?

Comment: It could be a DHCP issue since several Android versions are affected. (2.1 - 4.1.1 as far as I can remember). Did you try to set a static IP address?

Comment: No i didn't set a static IP, however i've found that my router always gives it the same address. Although, next time it plays up i'll definitely check the IP address.

Comment: It's android 4.4 i believe.

Comment: It hasn't failed in a while now to be honest, i'm a little puzzled as to what's going on.

Comment: hi @Chris  can  you say me what are you exert doing at android side? are you make APK or all time open server from safari browser from android?

Comment: @VishalPatel I wrote an article about it if you're still interested, i've thrown in the towel to be honest: http://www.splinter.com.au/2015/12/20/android-server/

Comment: yeeeh thank you @Chris   nice article  it may help lots in future.

Comment: It could bef a DOZE-related issue actually.

Comment: @Stan I believe DOZE is android M (6), I was using 4.x

Comment: @Chris do you have working solution for the Android M(6)? I have rooted tablet and I put server "whitelist" already but server still gets not accessible after unused time.

Comment: @AlperÖzaslan Sorry no. I assume android has aggressive sleeping of background apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason why it's stop working. There are ways to keep service running but try this line of code in your activity onCreate if this can help you out

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Debugging suggestions

When it becomes inaccessible, can you verify that the network connection is actually working? Not just showing up as "connected" in the UI, but actually working with HTTP connections to remote servers. Does your local HTTP server suddenly become accessible from remote when you do that? While poking, you could watch your server remotely:

```
watch curl http://{android_ip}:3000/
```

Do you keep the screen on or does the screen go off? It could be a buggy implementation of the PowerLock.

Does this happen with other wireless routers? It could be an issue with Wifi Power Save Mode (PSM).